# How to quantify "hash browns"

Tags: nouns, north-american-english, quantifiers

Does "hash browns" refer to a countable thing? Or a substance? Have I had *too many* or *too much* "hash browns"?

The word "browns" seems to imply a quantity. But, is there such a thing as a single hash brown? Or, are the strands just "pieces of hash browns"? (Or of "hash brown"!?)

Why does this all sound wrong??

Comment: Only when the hashed browns have been shaped into a patty would you have a context to say "two hashed browns". When they're served in a rather formless pile, it's like "mashed potatoes". You'd have to ask for "two *servings* of hashed browns".

Comment: The answers here indicate that there is a transatlantic difference. A dialect tag would help this question.

Comment: Sounds good. I've added the north American English tag.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_browns) has 'Triangular hash brown patties', perhaps shying away from the count usage (and introducing the problem of singular form, at least attributively) ... but there are reasonable numbers of examples of the countified usage on the internet, and I'm used to it at B & Bs. // Apparently, American food author Maria Parloa (1843–1909), in her 1887 Kitchen Companion, describes the dish "hashed and browned potatoes". Note that the compound noun 'mashed potatoes' is almost always used non-count (and typically with say 'is').

Comment: In my AmE dialect, "the mashed potatoes *are* tasty today".

Answer (score 3):

Hash browns come in either shaped individual patty things, or as a sort of dollop or clump of fried potato gratings.

In the patty case they are clearly countable: plural as in "a side order of three hash browns" or, yes, singular: "Do you want toast or a hash brown?"

When they're a clump of fried potatoes, it's not countable, it's just "hash browns"-- "that's a big side of hash browns!"

(North America, per the tag. No comment on other uses!)

Comment: What do you say when you've eaten too much or many? And why is it more correct whichever way you say it?

Comment: @svidgen - if they are served as a “clump” you will say…too much, if they are served as “patties” you will say.. too many.

Comment: "Too much hash browns"?

Comment: @svidgen 'Too many oats'? 'Five oats'?

Answer (score 0):

Hash browns are boiled potatoes that have been diced or shredded, mixed with chopped onions and shortening, and fried usually until they form a browned cake.

[Hash browns](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hash%20browns) is a plural noun (M-W)

so you can have  two hash browns, three hash browns etc.

[image]

From [The love diet](https://books.google.it/books?id=7JcqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT121&dq=%22two%20hash%20browns%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijpdLvpsiAAxU3iv0HHb3QCGoQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22two%20hash%20browns%22&f=false):

> Her favourite fried bread, baked beans, two eggs well done, two hash browns and toast.

From [The gunners](https://books.google.it/books?id=ueAREAAAQBAJ&pg=PT294&dq=%22three%20hash%20browns%22&hl=it&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIuuuDqsiAAxUMgP0HHSLfB6EQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22three%20hash%20browns%22&f=false):

> Alice always ordered three hash browns, a Coke, and a steak bagel for herself. The first time she had gotten this, Mikey watched as she ate the steak bagel.

Comment: In my experience, 'hash browns' most often come as an undifferentiated clump, not as a nicely formed cake, which would be a 'hash brown patty' or the like. One would not ask for 'another hash brown' but another 'order of hash browns', etc.

Comment: This is not idiomatic usage, in my West Coast American English experience.

Comment: If you can say "two hash browns", then you can also say "one hash brown", thus it can only be a normal count noun. Btw, MW is the worst, most out-of-date dictionary on the planet!

Comment: @BillJ: In the U.S., *hash browns* is not countable. *Two hash browns* in the U.S. means *two orders of hash browns*, just like *two coffees* and *two grits*. But one order of hash browns would generally be called *one hash browns* and one order of grits would be called *one grits*. Merriam-Webster is an American dictionary, and for *hash browns*, they are completely correct about American usage.

Comment: Wake up @PeterShor I never said anything about MW''s entry for hash browns, but merely that it's not a good dictionary (in general) -- notice that I also said btw. In any case, I was obviously talking of BrE (see my comment to Alphabet' answer below.

Comment: @BillJ: your comment "if you can say two hash browns, you can say one hash brown" is clearly wrong if you extend it to foods other than *hash browns*, because nobody would ever say *one grit*, even though in a restaurant *two grits* means *two orders of grits*.

Comment: @PeterShor I was referring only to hash browns. Read my comment to Alphabet again.

Comment: The non-count usage eg 'Hash Browns is a potato dish' is also in play. Plural-form, but taking a singular verb here, not accepting numerals.

Comment: I'm mostly used to seeing them as clumps. But most of the hits at images.google.com seem to be individual cakes.

Comment: Could hash browns be conceptualised so that each strand counts as **a** brown? That would make *hash brown(s)* an ordinary countable term so far as grammar is concerned, and still explain why the singular is never encountered in the wild (as there is practically never an occasion to say anything about a single strand of such potatoes). (As Professor Shor has convincingly argued, the fact that they are counted differently in the context of ordering food in a restaurant is not dispositive, as many kinds of food are in that context counted differently than in other contexts.)

Comment: @jsw29 You and Shor are thinking of the US only. In the UK, hash-browns are individual countable patties, so "hash-brown" is a countable NP: "I'll have two/three/four etc hash-browns please". See Tetsujin's answer, and the photo in this answer.

Comment: Hashbrowns (one word variation) are usually *scattered* in the U.S. Southeast because…two words: Waffle House. Some can still serve them as cakes, but it's rarely if ever done, and hashbrowns with onions would be *smothered.*